# HackerRank: Check Binary Search Tree: Python -test case -for duplications

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, testcase

The question related to HackerRAank -"Trees: Is This a Binary Search Tree?"https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-is-binary-search-tree/problem

Challange is to check if a giving tree is a binary search tree
Conditions: data in the left node will be smaller than root, data in the right node will be larger, values cannot be equal to the root.
Tree cannot contain duplications 
Code:

```
def check( root, min_number ,max_number):
    if root == None or (root.left == None and root.right == None): #Check empty tree
        return True
    elif root.data <= root.left.data or root.right.data <= root.data: #+Check dup
        return False
    elif root.data <= int(min_number) or root.data >= int(max_number):
        return False
    elif root.right == None:
        return root.left.data < root.data and check(root.left)
    elif root.left == None:
         return root.right.data > root.data and check(root.right)
    else:
        return check(root.left, int(min_number), root.data) and check(root.right, root.data, int(max_number))

def checkBST(root):
    return check(root,0,10000)# const given
```

Not all duplications are caught.

Test case (this is only an example):

> 2
>   1 2 3 4 6 8 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 16 18 19 21 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
>   78

Answer should be No

Any suggestion of which condition I missed I missed /what needs to be adjusted?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing too much, and at the same time doing too little. Consider this fragment:

```
elif root.data <= root.left.data or root.right.data <= root.data: #+Check dup
    return False
```

Now consider this one:

```
else:
    return check(root.left, int(min_number), root.data) and check(root.right, root.data, int(max_number))
```

If you're going to recurse, in the second fragment, then why do you need to bother "reaching down" into the children for the comparisons in the first fragment?

Also, why do you occasionally try converting your numbers to `int`? Aren't you satisfied that they are integers to begin with?

I'll suggest that you reduce the amount of code - get rid of the `int()` coercions that are not needed, and get rid of tests that are redundant. Instead, focus *only* on the current node. Finally, make a choice- are you using <= and >= or < and > comparisons? Do that for all your tests, and make sure you adjust your parameters appropriately. If your incoming min and max values are *inclusive* parameters, then use <= and >=, and make sure you add or subtract one when you recurse.

Comment: Regarding the int originally I added it after getting an error from the map code that is calling the function, now I removed it.
Regarding the duplication test, I added as a workaround in order to find what is missing in my test, and got the idea from several examples I checked online, even though logical it's repeating itself when I added it more test cases were successful.
I tried removing both of them and now even the basic case is not successful.
Still not sure what I'm missing in the basic condition?

Comment: Ok played with it more and found an example that instead of using root.data I should use -/+1, i.e.
 `    else:
        return check(root.left, min_number , root.data -1) and check(root.right, root.data +1, max_number)`
Not sure why  it is needed as Im using < > and not <= >= n

`def check(root, min_n, max_n):   
    if root == None:
        return True
    if root.data < min_n or root.data > max_n:
        return False
    return (check(root.left, min_n, root.data -1) and
          check(root.right, root.data+1, max_n))
def checkBST(root):
    return (check(root, 0, 10000))`